# Reshaping a dataframe / pivoting a slice of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question concerning reshaping a dataframe. In the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Alfred', 'Alfred', 'Arnaud', 'Arnaud', 'Agrest', 'Agrest'],
               'year': [2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017],
               'category': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'],
               'values': [-3, 4,-2, 4,-6,7],
               'kind': ['M', 'M', 'D', 'D', 'M', 'M']})
```

gives the following dataframe.

```
  category kind    name  values  year
0        x    M  Alfred      -3  2016
1        y    M  Alfred       4  2016
2        x    D  Arnaud      -2  2017
3        y    D  Arnaud       4  2017
4        x    M  Agrest      -6  2017
5        y    M  Agrest       7  2017
```

Please note that for each combination of 'name', 'kind' and 'year' we have one 'x' and one 'y' in 'category' column, and their corresponding values in the 'values' column.

How can I reshape the dataframe so that instead of a 'category' column I have two different ones, one labelled as 'x' and the other 'y'. I would like to get the following output.

```
  kind    name  x  y  year
0    M  Alfred -3  4  2016
1    D  Arnaud -2  4  2017
2    M  Agrest -6  7  2017
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
df.set_index(['name', 'year', 'kind', 'category']).unstack().reset_index()
```

You get

```
    name        year    kind    values
    category                    x   y
0   Agrest      2017    M       -6  7
1   Alfred      2016    M       -3  4
2   Arnaud      2017    D       -2  4
```

Comment: `df.set_index(['name', 'year', 'kind', 'category'])['values'].unstack().reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

A-Za-z's answer certainly works but might be a little cryptic. Here's one alternative:

```
df.pivot_table(values='values',index=['kind','name','year'],columns='category').reset_index()
```

or maybe even without `.reset_index()` depending on what you want.